# remove and reinstall/update stackdriver-agent

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

Is there another method of removing and reinstalling/updating stackdriver-agent after pinning it to a certain version beyond removing to reinstall the latest?

- stackdriver-agent.x86_64  5.5.2-1001.el7
- stackdriver-agent.x86_64 5.5.2-1002.el7

Running "install -y stackdriver-agent" still uses stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1002.el7 even after "remove stackdriver-agent".

Is there a config file to make this change before pulling/installing the latest version which is 6.*?

Comment: Can you provide detais what you've already tried ? Do you want to have specific version insalled and can't do that ? What's your goal - why do you need some version over the other ?

Comment: The agent was installed on prod systems and pinned to v5.+.

But that version is outdated even though it is still working.

Normally to update, you just `yum update`.

When you do that, you get:

`No packages marked for update`

Comment: Normally to remove the agent, you just run the usual "yum remove".

When you do, you get the expected behavior:


  `Erasing    : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1002.el7.x86_64       1/1`
  `Verifying  : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1002.el7.x86_64       1/1` 

`Removed: stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1002.el7`

Comment: Reinstall and run: `list --showduplicates`

You still get:


Available Packages
`stackdriver-agent.x86_64   5.5.2-1001.el7   google-cloud-monitoring`
stackdriver-agent.x86_64   5.5.2-1002.el7   google-cloud-monitoring`

Comment: Run:

`install -y stackdriver-agent` 

`Installed: stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1002.el7.x86_64`

Comment: Since it is just a normal CentOS 7 box, there are other approaches to try to force this. Before doing that, I'm trying to understand the odd behavior better since the logs haven't provided much to work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY way I was able to get the new version installed was to remove from all prod systems the logging agent first, then the agent, then reinstall.

```
stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:6.0.5-1.el7
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try going over the "[Installing the Cloud Monitoring agent on a single VM](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/installation)" documentation which I've went through.**

I was able to install, start, stop, remove and install another version of the agent.

**Here's how I did it (using CentOS 6 box):**

I've created a new CentOS 6 VM, added agent's repository to package list:

```
[wbogacz@centos ~]$ curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-monitoring-agent-repo.sh
[wbogacz@centos ~]$ sudo bash add-monitoring-agent-repo.sh
Adding agent repository for Red Hat.
```

Then listed all available versions for this OS:

```
[wbogacz@centos ~]$ sudo yum list --showduplicates stackdriver-agent
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.eu.oneandone.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: ftp.plusline.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.infonline.de
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: ftp.plusline.net
 * updates: ftp.plusline.net
google-cloud-monitoring/signature                                                        |  454 B     00:00     
google-cloud-monitoring/signature                                                        | 1.4 kB     00:00 ... 
Installed Packages
stackdriver-agent.x86_64                         5.5.2-1002.el6                         @google-cloud-monitoring
Available Packages
stackdriver-agent.x86_64                         5.5.2-1001.el6                         google-cloud-monitoring 
stackdriver-agent.x86_64                         5.5.2-1002.el6                         google-cloud-monitoring
```

Version 6 of the agent is not available for CentOS 6 (it shows in CentOS 8).

I then installed `1001` version:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.eu.oneandone.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: ftp.plusline.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.infonline.de
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: ftp.plusline.net
 * updates: ftp.plusline.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1001.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================
 Package                     Arch             Version                   Repository                         Size
================================================================================================================
Installing:
 stackdriver-agent           x86_64           5.5.2-1001.el6            google-cloud-monitoring           1.3 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 1.3 M
Installed size: 4.9 M
Downloading Packages:
85f2f9343af9e0c4669fb9214584c8d4c2ccacfd0a5559e7d980bc4ae85babc6-stackdriver-agent-5.5.2 | 1.3 MB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1001.el6.x86_64                                                      1/1 
  Verifying  : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1001.el6.x86_64                                                      1/1 

Installed:
  stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1001.el6                                                                     

Complete!
```

Listed installed agent's again and got nothing:

```
[wbogacz@centos ~]$  sudo yum list installed | grep stack
stackdriver-agent.x86_64
```

Started the agent:

```
[wbogacz@centos ~]$ sudo service stackdriver-agent start
Starting stackdriver-collectd: option = Interval; value = 60.000000;
option = Hostname; value = ;
option = FQDNLookup; value = false;
Created new plugin context.
option = PIDFile; value = /var/run/stackdriver-agent.pid;
option = Interval; value = 60.000000;
option = Hostname; value = ;
option = FQDNLookup; value = false;
Created new plugin context.
```

Remove the agent

```
[wbogacz@centos ~]$ sudo yum remove stackdriver-agent
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1001.el6 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================
 Package                     Arch             Version                  Repository                          Size
================================================================================================================
Removing:
 stackdriver-agent           x86_64           5.5.2-1001.el6           @google-cloud-monitoring           4.9 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================
Remove        1 Package(s)

Installed size: 4.9 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Erasing    : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1001.el6.x86_64                                                      1/1 
  Verifying  : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1001.el6.x86_64                                                      1/1 

Removed:
  stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1001.el6                                                                     

Complete!
```

Install `1002` version:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.eu.oneandone.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: ftp.plusline.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.infonline.de
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: ftp.plusline.net
 * updates: ftp.plusline.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1002.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================
 Package                     Arch             Version                   Repository                         Size
================================================================================================================
Installing:
 stackdriver-agent           x86_64           5.5.2-1002.el6            google-cloud-monitoring           1.3 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 1.3 M
Installed size: 4.9 M
Downloading Packages:
2a595a0373346006564e3ddc1a15101460b78d72936b11ba177ac956b125cca2-stackdriver-agent-5.5.2 | 1.3 MB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1002.el6.x86_64                                                      1/1 
  Verifying  : stackdriver-agent-5.5.2-1002.el6.x86_64                                                      1/1 

Installed:
  stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1002.el6                                                                     

Complete!
```

[Check installed version](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/installation#agent-version):

```
[wbogacz@centos ~]$ rpm --query --queryformat '%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n' \
>      stackdriver-agent
stackdriver-agent 5.5.2 1002.el6 x86_64
```